# Are apache's worker configuration and mod_wsgi's daemon mode related?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

So I don't get the relation between these two things.

For e.g. please explain what happens when I set up StartServers in worker configuration to 5 and processes=2 in WSGIDaemonProcess directive?

When we specify threads in WSGIDaemonProcess and when we specify ThreadsPerChild in worker configuration.. what exactly are we doing? How many threads will be running eventually?

I am confused because we have to specify the number of threads and processes in two places. Please explain the significance of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, go watch the following talks for a partial explanation.

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/
- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

In short, the Apache worker processes proxy requests to the mod_wsgi daemon mode processes if daemon mode is actually configured and the WSGI application delated properly to run in it.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I'll do that. Am I correct if I say that in a worker(apache) - embedded(mod_wsgi) configuration, there'll be exactly one interpreter running per apache process, given that I have one wsgi application? Btw, I found another useful resource here: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

Comment: Sort of. By default your WSGI application will run in a sub interpreter of the process. The main interpreter sits there idle. You can force one, which is a good idea for various reasons, by adding the directive 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'.